# Excel copy custom text

Tags: excel, function

I need a script that iterates over the column F and if there is a specific value(for example : me) in that column to write the response from column B on the respective row on B50+(B50 for the first given variable, B51 for the second etc).

Is this doable with excel existing functions?

I was able to do this

=IF(OR(F2="Ioan",F2="Robert"), B2, "false")

But I need something which work automatically, for all the rows

Thanks

Comment: So drag that function down...

Comment: [Here's a link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-excel-for-mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218) for @SolarMike 's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing your formula and drag down, start record macro and do what you done then stop it and assign this macro shortcut, save macro to Personel vba so you can use it in every excel workbook. After that with shortcut macro will do your job.